# How to determine what if any charge will actually occur when sending to an SMS short code

Tags: sms

I keep getting texts from a short SMS number asking me to fill out a survey, or reply "STOP" to stop getting these messages.  But when I reply "STOP", Android gives me the message:

```
this may cause charges on your mobile account
```

I did a Google Search for this message and found one specific service which said this is just referring to whatever charge your provider assesses to send texts, so with unlimited texting there would be no extra charge.  But the number that is sending me this message is not the service the web site is referring to, and I want to make sure that I'm not charged some extra amount just to opt out.

Is there some place I can do a lookup on the number that is texting me to see if there will be a charge and if so how much?  I have replied to other short codes before without ever having got this message so I assume there must be something to this number that I might need to worry about.

Comment: Is the number 10-digit ?

Comment: @PuspamAdak No, it has 5 digits.

Comment: According to my experience, generally Rs. 3 gets deducted for sending SMS to 5-digit numbers.

Comment: You can call your service provider and ask about the cost.